# Is there any way to make one page scroll in flutter?

Tags: flutter, slider, scrollview, onepage-scroll, customscrollview

I want to use CustomScrollView to make a SliverList where each child would be a full page Widget and I want them to be some kind of a vertical slider. How may I make it in flutter?

Comment: Could you post your code where you tried to solve the problem? Where are you stuck in? Stackoverflow is a place where we help with problems in your code, not a coding service.

Comment: Do wrap your page with SingleChildCrollView

Comment: PageView let’s you scroll one screen at a time.

Comment: Uni I don't have any because I can't find anything about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's exactly what you wanted but [carousel slider widget](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) might do this, if you use fullscreen mode.